# How can I see a detailed difference between files in the last git pull?

Tags: bash, git

I run a git pull and see that a file has changed. I would like to see a line by line difference of what has been added or removed.

I tried git diff 12345..67890 , (newest commit)..(second newest commit) , but the output showed a lot of additions where there is stuff missing from the file currently.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had it backwards it goes

```
git diff (second newest or even older commit)..(the newest or newer commit)
```

If you just want to see what changes since a commit you pulled in you can run

```
git diff (second newest or even older commit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `git whatchanged --patch` will show you what files have changed, along with the actual line changes. You can get similar results from the --patch flag with git-log, git-diff, and others--the flag isn't consistently documented on each sub-command, but it is generally available anywhere you'd get log output.